# Custom ordering in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have view:

```
class ContactListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,filters.OrderingFilter)
    ordering_fields = ['name']
    search_fields = ('name',)
```

Model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=2155, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=2155, blank=True, null=True)
```

I set ordering by `name` but name contains First Name and Last Name ,

I want to set order by `Last Name`

I created :

```
class SurnameOrdering(OrderingFilter):
    ordering_fields = ['surname']

    def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
        pass
```

but how set this ordering correctly?

Comment: Share the `Contact` model.

Comment: exactly how do you determine the last name from `name`. If the name is `Foo Bar Qux`, then what is the last name?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have only-- Foo Bar , so last name is second always

Answer (score 0):

We can annotate the querset with the `last_name` and perform an ordering for that:

```
from django.db.models import Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Substr, StrIndex


class ContactListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.annotate(
        last_name=Substr('name', StrIndex('name', V(' ')))
    )
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)
    ordering_fields = ('name', 'last_name')
    search_fields = ('name',)
```

here we thus let the database determine the `last_name`, and then we let the `OrderingFilter` filter on that `last_name`.